# Getting url data to show in the url bar

Tags: laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 and I'm trying to get the url bar to display the text url that is saved in the database instead of using the id.

This is my routes.php

```
Route::get('/{id}', function($id = 1){

if(is_numeric($id))
{

    $page = Menu::find($id);
    $action = 'content';
    return App::make('HomeController')->$action($id);
} else {
    $column = 'url';
    $url = Seo::where($column, '=', $id)->get();
    $action = 'show';
    return App::make('HomeController')->$action($url[0]->id);
}   
});
```

I'm also using a pivot table to link the menu to the seo.

Seo model

```
<?php

class Seo extends \Eloquent {
protected $fillable = array('url', 'meta_title', 'meta_description', 'keywords');
protected $guarded = array('id');

protected $table = 'seo';

public static $rules = array(
    'title' => '',
    'content' => '',
    'image' => ''
);

public function menu(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Menu', 'menu_seo', 'seo_id', 'menu_id');
}
}
```

Menu model

```
<?php

class Menu extends \Eloquent {
protected $fillable = array('title', 'menu_id', 'image');
protected $guarded = array('id');

protected $table = 'menus';

public static $rules = array(

    );

public function seo(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Seo', 'menu_seo', 'menu_id', 'seo_id');
}
}
```

HomeController

```
public function content($id)
{

    $menus_child = Menu::where('menu_id', 0)->with('menusP')->get();

    $menu = Menu::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

    //dd($menu->frames);
    return View::make('index', compact('menus_child'))->with('menu', $menu);
}
```

and then I call my views that references the menu like this

```
@foreach($menu->banner as $banners)
{{ $banners->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry I thought I had it up there. I would like the id to change to the url that I've added to the database

Comment: So you want to redirect from `/1` to `/foo-bar`? (or something similar) What I don't understand if `id` is the `Menu` id, how do you get the right url? Because it's a many-to-many relationship...

Comment: I get the right url because of my original route which is [code]Route::get('/{id}', 'HomeController@content');[/code] I've also updated my question to have my controller

Comment: Yes but a certain Menu (id) can have many Seo models assigned. Which can have different URLs. So to which URL do you want to redirect when `/123` is accessed?

Comment: well I would need for example `code`/123`code` to be `code`about-us.html`code` but I would need this to be dynamic and go according to my tables

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure how you want to retrieve the correct URL associated to an id but that shouldn't really matter. The basic principle is just to fetch the URL and make a redirect:

```
Route::get('/{id}', function($id = 1){
    if(is_numeric($id))
    {
        $page = Menu::find($id);
        $url = 'foo'; // get correct URL somehow
        return Redirect::to($url);
    } else {
        // ...
    }   
});
```

Comment: I tried that but now I'm getting this error.  `No query results for model [Menu].` I think it's suppose to mean that there is nothing in the database, but that isn't right because there is data in the database

Comment: If you're searching by a column that's not named `id` you can't use `find($id)` unless you specify the primary key in your model. Maybe that's the problem...

Comment: This is what I did to get the url `$page = Menu::where('id', $id)->first(); 

   foreach($page->seo as $seo){
    $url = $seo->url;
   }` This does get the correct url but I get that error thrown.

Comment: Is it possible that you still are calling the `content` method? Because this error is usually only thrown from `firstOrFail`

Comment: I am calling the content method

Comment: Are you doing the redirect in there? Or why would you otherwise call `content()`?